# Hibernate criteria joins multiple objects

Tags: java, hibernate, join, hibernate-criteria

i have a problem when retrieving count from criteria that impact my pagination.
i have this associations that work fine just the count of my result which is wrong for example i have 20 users in my DB but i got 60.

```
        DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(User.class, "user");
        criteria.createAlias("profile", "prof", Criteria.LEFT_JOIN);
        criteria.createAlias("userAgencyRole", "adminAgency", Criteria.LEFT_JOIN);
        criteria.createAlias("userAgencyRole.agency", "agency",Criteria.LEFT_JOIN);
        criteria.createAlias("userAgencyRole.role", "role",Criteria.LEFT_JOIN);
        
        
        result.setTotalRecords(userDalService.getCountFromCriteria(criteria));
```

For used projections i have :

```
            ProjectionList projList = Projections.projectionList();
            projList.add(Projections.property("name"), "name");
            projList.add(Projections.property("email"), "email");
            projList.add(Projections.property("userId"), "userId");
            projList.add(Projections.property("profile"), "profile");
```

Any suggestions for this issue

Answer (score 0):

You have to be careful while using Criteria API since joining a one-to-many relationship will not return distinct results by default.
This is a known problem and there are a few ways to prevent it. Some of them are discussed [here](https://xebia.com/blog/sorting-and-pagination-with-hibernate-criteria-how-it-can-go-wrong-with-joins/).

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by invoking criteria alias if needed based on parameters received from my API. so the result wont be impacted by associations.